# Apache mod_proxy, tomcat 5.5 - sometimes no response

Tags: .htaccess, tomcat, mod-proxy

Running tomcat 5.5 with (64 bit centos, 8 gb ram), mysql, apache

```
"-server -Xss1M -Xms2G -Xmx3550m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=1G -XX:MaxPermSize=512m XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70"
```

running multiple application on tomcat via apache as front end (almost 10 domains for various context paths on tomcat)

```
apache config:
httpd.conf:

KeepAlive On

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPreserveHost On

Timeout 1800

ProxyPass         /demo  http : //127.0.0.1:8080/demo

ProxyPassReverse  /demo  http :// 127.0.0.1.22:8080/demo

ProxyPass         /demo2  http :// 127.0.0.1:8080/demo2

ProxyPassReverse  /demo2  http :// 127.0.0.1.22:8080/demo2

SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1

SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

.htaccess

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.web\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http : //test.web.com/demo/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test2\.web\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http : //test2.web.com/demo2/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Everything works great, including response time and all 10 instances (various domains), but 3-4 times a day: http://test.web.com does not give any response, it throws blank page (completely blank) while at the time when its blank, direct url: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/demo` works fine. It means tomcat still works fine, it seems apache is not able to forward the request to tomcat - right now load on per instance is 20 per minute.

Sometime everything works for 3-4 days, then it happens, sometimes it keeps on happening. Blank page comes for some time - and after 3-4 minutes - page starts coming.

Answer (score 0):

Try using JKMount rather than your proxy config?

I have something similar with apache config:

```
# 
# Mod_jk settings 
# 
JkWorkersFile "conf/workers.properties" 
JkLogFile "logs/mod_jk.log" 
JkLogLevel info

# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "

# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE, 
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format 
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"


<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile conf/ssl/domainacom.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/ssl/domainacom.key
    ServerAdmin boss@domain.com
    ServerName wwwdomainacom
    ErrorLog logs/wwwdomainacom-error_log
    CustomLog logs/wwwdomainacom-access_log common
    JkMount /* wwwdomainacom
</VirtualHost>
```

---

then in conf/workers.properties:

```
worker.list=domainacom,domainbcom

# Set properties for domainacom (ajp13) 
worker.domainacom.port=8009
worker.domainacom.host=localhost
worker.domainacom.type=ajp13
worker.domainacom.lbfactor=50
worker.domainacom.cachesize=10
worker.domainacom.cache_timeout=600
worker.domainacom.socket_keepalive=1
worker.domainacom.reclycle_timeout=300

# Set properties for domainbcom (ajp13) 
worker.domainbcom.port=8011
worker.domainbcom.host=localhost
worker.domainbcom.type=ajp13
worker.domainbcom.lbfactor=50
worker.domainbcom.cachesize=10
worker.domainbcom.cache_timeout=600
worker.domainbcom.socket_keepalive=1
worker.domainbcom.reclycle_timeout=300
```

---

finally in tomcat:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" 
           enableLookups="true" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

as far as i know, i never have any lost requests.

Comment: I have removed mod_proxy completely, and now its tomcat virtual hosting (multiple) - still we are getting this. There is no entry in logs, and app does handle 100 concurrent users. But still sometimes there is no response, its blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Load Balancer? Please make sure its not PING based. Sometimes hosting provider rejects pings based network load.